# Plotly xaxis formatting when saving to the file

Tags: python, graph, formatting, plotly

I am writing a quick script to generate some data visualization that has to be exported to png. What I want to achieve is variety of displayed values in my xaxis. I am using the code below for formatting:

```
graph = go.Figure(data=[...])
graph.update_layout(
  barmode='stack', 
  title_text=job,
  showlegend=True,
  xaxis = {
     'tickformat': '%b, %d',
     'tickmode': 'array',
     'nticks': len(weeks),
     'ticktext': weeks
  }
)
graph.write_image('{}_stats.png'.format(job))
```

`weeks` is array of datetime objects, which looks like:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 0, 0)]
```

You can see that difference between first 2 elements is 5 days, when for others it's 7 days. 
The format below generates a picture with the following xaxis:

[image]

How to get the actual dates from array displayed on the picture?
[image]

Comment: So you want the last item to display as Sep, 13?

Comment: @user2379875 yes